# How does the parent class's defined method get called in a sub-class object?

Tags: java

This is a bit more of an implementation-related question, or I could be overthinking it. Let's say I have a subclass that inherits from the parent class. From my understanding, it will inherit the method definitions from the parent class but not the constructor. We need to provide or the compiler will provide constructor through the super method call. The reason we do this is that the method definitions we obtain from the parent class in the sub class will not exist without a parent class object instance.

Does this mean, when I call a parent class object defined method that is not overridden yet in the subclass, will be internally called inside the subclass on a parent object instance? I was thinking that would be the case since the sub-class does call the parent class constructor and make an instance of it.

Answer (score 2):

I think you have been mislead by the term "constructor". If the wording had been "initializer", IMHO that would have been clearer - but the established term is "constructor".

If your subclass `Sub` extends a parent class `Parent`, then creating a `Sub` instance will not create a second, separate `Parent` instance.

When your `Sub` constructor calls the `super()` constructor, this just means that the aspects described in the `Parent` class get initialized the way that `Parent` constructor wants it, e.g. filling the fields defined in `Parent` with appropriate values. This `super()` constructor call does not construct/create a new instance, but initializes the `Parent`-defined part of the one and only instance, and that's why I think the name "constructor" misleading.

After that `super()` call, your `Sub` constructor is free to do its turn. All this happens on a single instance that combines fields (and methods) from both classes.

So, when you call a `Parent`-defined method on a `Sub` instance, there is no distinct `Parent` instance that might receive the call, it all happens on the single `Sub` instance. As the method is defined inside `Parent`, it does not know anything about the `Sub` extensions to `Parent`, and e.g. can't access fields defined in Sub (unless using "dirty tricks" like reflection).

If you like, you can think of a `Sub` instance as being a `Parent` instance where some fields and methods have been added to the end. `Parent`-defined methods work on the `Parent` part of the instance(1), and `Sub` methods see the complete instance.

> The reason we do this is that the method definitions we obtain from
> the parent class in the sub class will not exist without a parent
> class object instance.

So, this is not true. The "parent class object instance" does not exist (at least not in the sense of an instance distinct from the subclass one), it is the first part of the subclass instance, which is then followed by the subclass fields.

(1) There are a few caveats, e.g. if a `Parent` method is overridden in the `Sub` class, but IMHO that goes beyond the scope of this question.